# Submenu disapear on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my big project I have a problem. The code is too big to post here in its entirety, but I've created an example on jsfiddle.

I have a dynamic menu with a submenu section.

I would like on hover certain menu item to show certain box container.

Problem is when hover over menu item I can't access to box container, because it's not inside `<li>` element, because it's loading dynamically.

I have idea to create function, on hover menu item to show  box container and to check when mouseout of menu item and box container to hide box container.

That will be solution for my problem, I've tried mouseout and mouseleave, but not working.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XWRZF/30/)

```js
$('.first-menu-item, .submenu').hover(function() {
  $('.submenu').toggle();
});
```

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="first-menu-item">FIRST MENU</li>
  <li>SECOND MENU</li>
  <li>THIRD MENU</li>
</ul>


<div class="submenu">
  SUBMENU
</div>
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing this in CSS: http://www.cssterm.com/css-menus/horizontal-css-menu/simple-drop-down-menu. It's better supported and quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix would be to add the same logic for when hovering on the submenu:

```
$('.first-menu-item, .submenu').hover(function(){
  $('.submenu').toggle();
});
```

But there are better ways to implement submenus in a list-like navigation (e.g like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159050/dropdown-submenu-disappears-on-hover)). However, with your solution, this is what I would do.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XWRZF/31/)

But again, you should reconsider your implementation of the submenu. See Rory's suggestion for example.